# Is passing gherkin table value to IList<string> rather than a regular string property supported?

Tags: c#, testing, cucumber, specflow, gherkin

I have a table written in gherkin for an object that I'm passing values to as such:

```
    | Description | Perils |
    | foo         | 6      |
```

There are much more values being passed but these two above are taken for example.

In the binding, I'm  retrieving this table data and putting it into an object type of `Cover`. It has a regualr property called `Description` that will be able to take the string `foo` from the table and set it to that property fine. However my issue is with Perils. This is not a regular property but rather an `IList<string>`. I would like to pass the value `6` from Perils to that property somehow, but the `AssistHelper` might not support that. I've tried changing the header to `Peril[0]` though I knew that was pointless. Any suggestions?

```
var tempTable = table.CreateInstance<Cover>();
var thisNeedsToBeSix = tempTable.Perils[0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your SpecFlow tests only use one Peril, then you could create a CoverWrapper instead of using Cover directly e.g.

The binding could look as follows:

```
[Given(@"Given I entered the following data into the new form:")]
public void x(Table table)
{
    var coverWrapper = table.CreateInstance<CoverWrapper>();
}
```

The CoverWrapper could look like:

```
public class CoverWrapper
{
 private Cover cover;

 public CoverWrapper()
 {
  cover = new Cover();
 }

 public string Description
 {
  get
  {
   return cover.Description;
  }
  set
  {
   cover.Description = value;
  }
 }

 public string Peril
 {
  get
  {
   return cover.Perils[0];
  }
  set
  {
   cover.Perils.Add(value);
  }
 }

 public GetCover()
 {
  return cover;
 }
}
```

You could then call coverWrapper.GetCover() to return an instance of Cover as you want it.

Note that I haven't compiled that code so apologies if something is not quite right.

Comment: Yes, this is similar to the work around I encorporated. I created an instance from the table of Peril's type CoverFilter instead of "CoverWrapper". It works, however I have to do this for each property I'm checking against that is not a direct and simple property of the main table derived object. There's got to be a simpler way, no? I think I may just have to go back and examine how I have my tests are structured, and possibly extract them out rather than trying to group too many that aren't as directly related together.

Comment: I agree that this may get messy if you have to do this for all the IEnumerable members you have. Changing the way that you write the tests could be good too e.g. if you have many "Perils" you could write a "When" where the step definition simply calls the Add method on the collection to push the new value in. It'll be interesting to hear how you progress!

Answer (score 0):

How about make your perils argument just a `string` and then use `string.Split()` to break it up inside your binding?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is out of the question. Perils has definitely got to stay an `IList<string>`, it's used for much more than my simple little test here.

Comment: Would an `implicit` conversion `operator` help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx. Maybe c# can convert it to help SpecFlow